# Using the built in alarm system, not just alarm manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, clock, alarm

I writing something that schedules events at various time. Right now I just create a pendingintent and use the alarm manager to call a broadcast receiver at a specific time. This then calls a transparent activity with a dialog box and runs vibration/ a media player to mimic an alarm clock. One of the problems with this, is that then the alarm is privy to the media volume settings rather than the alarm volume settings.

Another problem is, I'd like users to be able to see the alarm amongst the system alarms. I would imagine this has something to do with it http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html

But it doesn't seem like you have control over things like ringtone, vibration pattern, volume etc. At the very least I'd like to play an alarm sound which volume is not affected by the media volume levels.

What is the best solution here for creating an alarm that really mimics the system and feels to be integrated with android very well? I'm stumped as every search I do just brings up info about alarmmanager

Answer (score 0):

> One of the problems with this, is that then the alarm is privy to the media volume settings rather than the alarm volume settings.

You can tell `MediaPlayer` [what volume stream to use](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType%28int%29).

> But it doesn't seem like you have control over things like ringtone, vibration pattern, volume etc.

Correct. The `AlarmClock` `ContentProvider` is providing data for the device's built-in `AlarmClock` application. It is not providing data for you.

> At the very least I'd like to play an alarm sound which volume is not affected by the media volume levels.

You can tell `MediaPlayer` [what volume stream to use](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType%28int%29).

> What is the best solution here for creating an alarm that really mimics the system and feels to be integrated with android very well?

The user is perfectly capable of using the device's built-in `AlarmClock` application for this.

Comment: Thank you for the link! I missed that.

Regarding the user using the built in alarm clock. The application is something for shifting sleep schedules. You set your current sleep schedule and your desired sleep schedule, and each day the application shifts your wake time/ sleep time accordingly, and sets off an alarm at those times. For a user to have to set these preferences every day it would be very cumbersome. However, if on a specific day, they could adjust that days alarm settings it would be nice. Or, if preferred, they could change the settings for ALL set alarms in the application.

Comment: @user1123861: All the built-in alarm clock allows outside apps to do is add alarms. For your use case, you will need to create your own alarm clock app.